# Is It Possible to Have Two Axis Labels for a Chart in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

This is a pretty straight forward question but I can't seem to figure out how to do it!
I am making a stacked bar chart in Crystal Reports.
The x-axis any date in order in the range: 04/01/2010 --> 31/12/2010.
The y-axis value is an integer value.

Basically I have a field called CalenderDate and a field called WeekNo. Is there anyway that for each date on the x axis label I can get the week number to be grouped beneath it?

Appreciate any help! I'm probably being dopey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you're not being dopey this morning.  Your request makes sense (I've had the same idea myself), but I haven't found a way yet (at least in Crystal).  Here's one thing you can do:

1. Make sure you have a record for **every day** in your time period. If not, you might need to make a helper table to right join to.  (I can help you with this step if you need)
2. Set your x-axis as the date field.
3. In your graph, **right click**->**Group (X) Axis Options**->**Skip Group Labels** and "7" as the option.

For example, if your graph starts at 01/01/2010 (let's pretend that was a Monday), then you will see 01/01/2010, then 01/08/2010, then 01/16/2010 on your x-axis with all 7 data points between them.

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but it's an alternative that might be just as good.

Comment: Hey that wasn't exactly what I was looking for but thanks a lot for your time and help I appreciate it. Plus you've answered the question "can it be done or not" :).Thanks Again.